# Why does col-sm-12 add a margin that col-sm does not in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I noticed that my website was looking well on desktop, but on my phone something was off. In short, my website was of the form

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"> <!-- content A --> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"> <!-- content B --> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"> <!-- content C --> </div>
</div>
<div class="row>
    <!-- content D -->
</div>
```

What I noticed: The second row had no white space on the left side.
First approach: changing `content D` to `<div class="col-sm">content D</div>`.
Nothing changed.
Second approach fixed it: changing `content D` to `<div class="col-sm-12">content D</div>`.

It's worth noting that `col-sm-4` has the same effect on the margin.
**Now I'd like to know what the difference is between using no column, `"col-sm"`, and `"col-sm-12"`.**

col-sm ("Projects" is too far to the left):
[image: bad]

col-sm-12:
[image: good]

Obviously, somehow the width of the header for "Projects" is changed, but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing the `15px` padding when you use `col-sm` is because `col-sm` is not defined for **Bootstrap 3** thus basically `col-sm` is not really having any effect in the padding. The `col-*` classes were introduced in **Bootstrap 4**. Below is an excerpt from `bootstrap 3`:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, 
.col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, 
.col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, 
.col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, 
.col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, 
.col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

As you can see, `col-sm` is not defined. If we look at `bootstrap 4` though

```
.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, 
.col, .col-auto, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, 
.col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm, .col-sm-auto, .col-md-1, .col-md-2,
.col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, 
.col-md-12, .col-md, .col-md-auto, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, 
.col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg, .col-lg-auto, 
.col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9,
.col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl,
.col-xl-auto {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

There you can see `col-sm` right after `col-sm-12`